# Updating Siyah Kernel to 1.9.1 on Galxy SIII i9300 ends in black screen after Siyah logo

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, kernel

I currently run Siyah 1.8.9 Kernel with CM 10.1 nightly (20130218), and I've tried to flash Siyah 1.9.1 with both Odin (PC) and through CM recovery. Both ways end up with a black screen after the Siyah logo. I've wiped cache and dalvik as well and fixed permissions.

I'm not sure what the problem is. GM's website seems to support the CM 10.1 nightly I'm running. Am I missing something in stweaks setup? Something else?